# Fuentes en terminales iOS

Tags: html, css, fuentes

El otro día me reportaron un error respecto a las tipografías que uso en una página web. Os muestro una imagen de como se visualiza ese problema:

[image]

Como podéis ver en la imagen, las tíldes y las ñ se ven sin la tipografía de la letra. Cierto, pero solo con dispositivos iOS que haya podido comprobar (iPhone).

Así que cogí otro dispositivo (Android esta vez), y ese problema no se reproduce. En versión desktop este problema tampoco ocurre ni en Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE...

En otras respuestas comentaban de mejorar en `<meta charset="utf-8">` por el `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` pero no solucionó nada. El problema pues no parece ser de ese tag, ya que las tipografías se renderizan bien en todos los demás SO y dispositivos.

¿Alguna razón por qué hace eso? ¿Y cómo puedo solventarla?

Answer (score 0):

No se si será el caso, pero yo tenía el mismo problema a la hora de visualizar mis proyectos en dispositivos iOS, lo arreglé aplicando esta regla de manera general:

```
* {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar, lo pruebo en cuanto pueda y te digo si valió esta solución!